# Union with simply connected set

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $U$ and $V$ be open and path-connected sets in $X$ such that $U$ is simply connected and $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$ is path-connected. Is it true that $\pi_1(U \cup V) = \pi_1(V)$? If not, is there a condition under which this is true? (I believe this would follow from Van-Kampen, but not sure)

Comment: Let $X=\mathbb R^2.$ $U$ be an open disk $\{z\in\mathbb R^2\mid |z|<2\}$ and $V=\{z\mid 1<|z|<3\}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks! So is $\pi_1(U \cup V)$ a quotient group of $\pi_1(V)$? What is it a quotient by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem of Seifert - van Kampen says that
$$\pi_1(U \cup V) \approx (\pi_1(U) * \pi_1(V))/N$$
where $*$ denotes the free product and $N$ is the normal subgroup generated by all elements of the form
$$(i_U)_*(g)^{-1}(i_V)_*(g)$$
where $g \in \pi_1(U \cap V)$ and $i_U : U \cap V \to U$ and $i_V : U \cap V \to V$ are the inclusion maps. Note that $(i_U)_*(g)^{-1}(i_V)_*(g)$ is a **word** with $(i_U)_*(g) \in \pi_1(U)$ and $(i_V)_*(g) \in \pi_1(V)$.

We have $\pi_1(U) = 0$, thus

- $\pi_1(U) * \pi_1(V) = \pi_1(V)$
- $N$ is the normal subgroup generated by the image of $(i_V)_*$.